# MySQL GROUP BY is slower with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

## What we're trying to accomplish:

**Basically we are collecting some 1-to-1 metadata about users (name, address) and then we are doing some summary reporting on their orders.**

## Query 1

```
SELECT
    -- STUDENT DATA
       wp_users.user_email AS 'email',

    -- STUDENT METADATA
       um_fn.meta_value AS 'first_name',
       um_ln.meta_value AS 'last_name',
       ### MANY MORE ###

    -- ORDER DATA
       MAX(pmt_orders.order_date) last_order,
       MIN(pmt_orders.order_date) first_order,
       COUNT(pmt_order_course.fk_order_id) life_courses,
       ### MANY MORE AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS ###

  FROM wp_users

      ### LEFT OUTER JOINS, INNER JOINS, LEFT JOINS (FOR THE AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS) ###

    -- STUDENT METADATA
       LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um_fn ON wp_users.id = um_fn.user_id AND um_fn.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name'
       LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um_ln ON wp_users.id = um_ln.user_id AND um_ln.meta_key = 'shipping_last_name'
       ### MANY MORE ###

 WHERE pmt_order_course.unenroll_date IS NULL OR pmt_order_course.unenroll_date = '0000-00-00'

 GROUP BY wp_users.user_email
```

**TIME: 13 seconds**

We started investigating and I broke this into one metadata query (0.5 sec) and the other stuff (2 sec). Basically just splitting the columns into two separate queries.

Note: I did try adding every non-aggregating selection into the `GROUP BY` so that we would be strict mode compliant. Zero impact on performance.

## Query 2

Perplexed, then we turned it back into one large query. The approach was to move the non-aggregating selection into an outer select.

```
SELECT users.*,

    -- STUDENT METADATA
       um_fn.meta_value AS 'first_name',
       um_ln.meta_value AS 'last_name',
       ### MANY MORE ###

  FROM (

SELECT
    -- STUDENT DATA
       wp_users.ID,
       wp_users.user_email AS 'email',

    -- ORDER DATA
       MAX(pmt_orders.order_date) last_order,
       MIN(pmt_orders.order_date) first_order,
       COUNT(pmt_order_course.fk_order_id) life_courses,
       ### MANY MORE AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS ###

  FROM wp_users

       ### LEFT OUTER JOINS, INNER JOINS, LEFT JOINS (FOR THE AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS) ###

 WHERE pmt_order_course.unenroll_date IS NULL OR pmt_order_course.unenroll_date = '0000-00-00'

 GROUP BY wp_users.user_email

       ) AS users

    -- STUDENT METADATA
       LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um_fn ON users.id = um_fn.user_id AND um_fn.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name'
       LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um_ln ON users.id = um_ln.user_id AND um_ln.meta_key = 'shipping_last_name'
       ### MANY MORE ###
```

**TIME: 2 seconds**

## Results

Query 2 produces identical results and is mathematically equivalent to Query 1. It runs in 2 sec.

I can understand why, MySQL is looking up the metadata once for each order and then aggregating by user, rather than looking up the metadata once per user.

Some profiling data: the `wp_users` table is large, and the aggregating rows are about two rows per user.

## Question

Why didn't the MySQL optimizer figure this out by itself? Is there another way I could write the query that looks more expressive (like Query 1) while causing MySQL to use the faster execution path of Query 2?

Comment: I think to answer your question professionally, we need your execution plan. Please Write EXPLAIN before your query and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say keep in mind in query 1 you are joining on the users table the number of times of the rest of the unaggregated query records.

However, in query 2, you are only joining on the number of times of the aggregated data.

That's why its different.

If all you need is first name and last name, I guess you could do a subquery to get the first name and last name perhaps rather than um_fn.meta_value, but if option 2 is fast, you might be best off just leaving it alone (or adding comments that no one will read).  Here's something to try though in query 1 that might be more readable?

```
(SELECT um_fn.meta_value FROM wp_usermeta um_fn ON wp_users.id = um_fn.user_id AND um_fn.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name') as 'first_name',
(SELECT um_ln.meta_value FROM wp_usermeta um_ln ON wp_users.id = um_ln.user_id AND um_ln.meta_key = 'shipping_last_name') as 'last_name',
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper indexes in place for the first query?

Try adding:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_usermeta` ADD INDEX `wp_usermeta_index_1` (`meta_key`, `user_id`, `meta_value`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_users` ADD INDEX `wp_users_index_1` (`id`, `user_email`);
```

Also, add an explicit ORDER BY clause wherever you have a GROUP BY clause. If there is no point in ordering, add ORDER BY NULL to avoid redundant orders (which reduces performance).

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:  The Optimizer does not (or can not) do all the optimizations you imagine.  Why not?  You are getting a lot of good stuff for free.  It takes years to crank out more free stuff in MySQL.

Problem 2:  "Explode-Implode" -- `JOINs` increase the number of rows to look at, then `GROUP BY` shrinks back to what you started with.  Ctznkane525 partially addresses this.

Problem 3:  Key-Value (EAV) schema really sucks for performance; there is not much that can solve it other than abandon the concept.

Problem 4:  WP's "meta" data is EAV.  See Problem 2.

Problem 5:  WP has lousy indexes on wp_postmeta.  Partial solution:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta  (Perhaps "post_id" needs to be replaced by "user_id" in that reference.)  Note that this goes beyond what Tomer suggests.

Problem 6:  MySQL has no answer for "summary tables".  I'm not sure if such would be useful for you, but here is a discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables